# Laravel import validation errors while data exist in file

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am using [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) and have issue with importing my data from csv file.

When I try to import my CSV file it returns back validation errors

```
errors: {name: ["The name field is required."], stock: ["The stock field is required."],…}
  name: ["The name field is required."]
  price: ["The price field is required."]
  stock: ["The stock field is required."]
  message: "The given data was invalid."
```

While I have all this data presented in my CSV file

[image: Capture]

## Code

**Import class**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Product;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;

class ProductsImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
{
    use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Product([
            'name'     => $row['name'],
            'stock'    => $row['stock'],
            'sku'    => $row['sku'],
            'price'    => $row['price'],
            'bottom_price'    => $row['bottom_price'],
            'cover'    => $row['cover'],
        ]);
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
    public function import(Request $request) 
    {
        Excel::import(new ProductsImport, $request->file('file'));

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Products are successfully imported.'
        ]);
    }
```

**Route**

```php
    Route::post('products/import', 'Api\ProductsController@import');
```

**Any idea what could be wrong?**

## Update

`Component script`

```
importFile() {
    this.importFile = this.$refs.importFile.files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.importFile, this.importFile.name);


    axios.post( '/api/admin/products/import', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        }
    }).then(res => {
        this.$notify({
            title: 'Hooray!',
            message: res.data.message,
            offset: 100,
            type: 'success'
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        var errors = error.response.data;
        let errorsHtml = '<ol>';
        $.each(errors.errors,function (k,v) {
            errorsHtml += '<li>'+ v + '</li>';
        });
        errorsHtml += '</ol>';

        this.$notify.error({
            title: 'Import Error',
            dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
            message: errorsHtml
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: How are you getting the validation errors, Do you have a request validation class in between. I cant see it in the code!

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami i get errors from component when post request is processed (i will update my questin)

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami updated.

Comment: Where does the validation come from? there is nothing in your `ProductsImport` that validates?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert exactly, i do not have any validation for file upload yet i get the errors it comes as error `422`

Comment: In any case you need to have `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;`

`class ProductsImport implements ToModel, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading, WithHeadingRow` try to add that first

Comment: that didn't change anything :/

Comment: Do you have a middleware somewhere on your API route that is validating the `$request`? Can you `dd($request)` before running the `Excel::import()`?

Comment: no my route only protected by auth middleware which i'm sending token in header `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {`

Comment: Can you please `dd($request->all())` before running the `Excel::import()` and share the output?

Comment: i think issue is from `formData` this is what i get in console `my form data: FormData {}__proto__: FormData`

Comment: seems like it doesn't get the file from input

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami updated my question.

Comment: `/api/admin/products/import` Where is your `admin` in your route.

Comment: @A.ANoman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61537405/laravel-import-validation-errors-while-data-exist-in-file/61538040#comment108854720_61537405  is prefix

Comment: Hey sorry about that, Got busy somewhere, I hope your problem is resolved!

Comment: @SomangshuGoswami no problem man is already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

Problem was coming from routes, somehow having my import route under prefixed group was causing `422` error. after placing my route on top of `api.php` file it works just fine.